# How to add layers to pre-trained SSD model from tensorflow Object Detection API model zoo

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

I am trying to add new layers at the end to a pre-trained SSD mobilenet v1 model from tensorflow Object Detection API, but couldn't find anyway to do this. Do I need to re-define the whole model in the form of DetectionModel? or is there any simpler way to add new layers/neurons. Basically, I want to predict 3D boxes also with 2D boxes.

Comment: This is not a place to ask such questions, please refrain from asking general questions which are not related to programming. Please read "What topics can I ask about here?". A second visit to the tour would also enlighten you on the subject. Please refer to other stack exchange websites

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar, I'm new here. This question is related to **Where to start?**
Can you please point me in the direction where to ask these types of questions.